# Convert Lead to a Contact for an Account not owned by user

Tags: account, leads

I am trying to design a method to allow sales people to convert leads to accounts not owned by them.  The current settings for their profile only allows them to edit their own accounts.  I cannot find any settings for Leads that will allow visibility of other reps accounts.  I was thinking of changing the base security and then creating a validation rule to block other changes if the owner is not the user.  We are getting too many duplicate accounts with this setup. Has anyone else tried to do this?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If opening up permissions doesn't cause other issues (i.e. allows the users to view accounts they shouldn't) this is a great approach.

I've done something similar to restrict the ability to delete a record to just those owned by the current user.

1. Give everyone delete perms
2. Add a beforeDelete trigger
3. Check if the record's ownerid matches the current user
4. If yes, do nothing
5. If no, thrown an exception

I'm sure there are other snags you'll run into in implementing the approach, lead conversion is generally kind of idiosyncratic, but the general approach of opening up permissions at the profile level, and then restricting them at another (i.e. trigger or validation rule) is sound.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was hoping someone out there might know of a "little known" configuration in the system that would allow non owners to convert a lead into a contact on an existing account.  Guess I will need to take the hard way.